# Building all ABIs but packaging only a subset

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I am attempting to build all ABIs for my project but would only like to package a subset of them into my app.  For example, I would like to build "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a" and "arm64-v8a" but only package "x86" (for example).

Reading this document (https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds.html#jniLibs) under section "Specify ABIs", it seems very possible using the snippet they provided as an example.  However, this does not seem to be working for me.

My code snippet is as follows.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

In the snippet above, from my understanding of the document, it should build both armeabi-v7a and x86, but only package armeabi-v7a in my APK.  This is not working though.

I am using Android plugin 3.1.0 and NDK 16.1.4479499

Comment: I believe that your interpretation of [abiFilters](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions:abiFilters) is incorrect. The idea to have this list defined twice may help if you want to package, e.g., both **x86** and **armeabi**, but have the former prebuilt, and only want Gradle to build **armeabi**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for, is controlled by splits.

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk false //don't generate an additional APK that contains all the ABIs
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Wouldn't this create multiple APKs though? I was hoping to create single APK with only a single ABI but build all ABIs.

Comment: While you only need one ABI, the setup above is enough. I don't know how to create an APK with two ABIs while building more.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex.  The code I posted in my original question should theoretically work but for some reason it isn't :( I upvoted your reply because it was very helpful but I would still like to understand why the sample code doesn't work.